# How to use yarn instead of npm in Visual Studio React project?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, yarnpkg, publish

I've created a VS 2022 project using the VS out of the box ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux template.

When I publish the project I see in the output window it uses `npm install` command.

**Question**

How can I modify the build/publish process to use `yarn build` command instead of `npm install`?

Answer (score 1):

In the project's .csproj file I've changed the following lines:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
```

to:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="yarn" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="yarn build" />
```

(additionaly I've changed the build process accordingly:)

```
<Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
```

to:

```
<Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'yarn'. This may take several minutes..." />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="yarn" />
```

Answer (score -1):

First, install yarn globally with npm.

```
npm install --global yarn
```

```
yarn --version
```

The installation method varies by OS depending on Windows and Mac.

Then, you can run the division that was run with npm with yarn. You can run it with 'yarn start' , 'yarn bulid', etc. without 'run' such as 'npm run start'.

```
npm run start
```

if use yarn

```
yarn start
```

Comment: Many thx, but the question was not about how to use yarn, I do know I can build my app with yarn build. The question was about how to modify VS 2022 publish process (MSBuild) in the project template to use the yarn build command instead npm command